# How to send data to a rest endpoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I'm looking at the autocompleter at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

I'm looking for a callback that will send the data of a textbox to 'rest' service as the user types.

So if user types 'a' into text box -

> myservice?parameter=a

is sent

if then 'b' is entered into textbox (appended to 'a')

> myservice?parameter=ab

is sent

Is there a callback or way of doing this using the jQuery autocompleter ? I've looked at the 'source' callback but this just seems to get static content ?

Comment: Did you have a look at their example for a remote datasource: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: @xbonez yes, in that example 'source.php' is just called once. I need to call 'source.php' as the user types in a text box. So everytime a character is entered a call is made to 'source.php'

Comment: jQueryUI autocomplete will send the data every keystroke, with param name `term` by default. Look in browser console while using the demo, will see each request made as each new letter added

Comment: @charlietfl I should have checked that first. put your comment into an answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQueryUI autocomplete will send the data every keystroke, with param name `term` by default. Look in browser console while using the  [**remote demo**](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) will see each request made as each new letter added